# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app saying index.cshtml not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am creating a new .NET 6.0 application in Visual Studio 2022. When I run the default `HomeController`, the application is throwing a runtime exception saying `index.cshtml` was not found. But in the `Views` folder, I am able to see that file.

[image: Solution Explorer having views]

[image: Exception Image]

`program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this happen with every new project you create? Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: How are  you building and running?   Are you just debugging it?   Using dotnet, or iis express?  Try closing VS, removing your '.vs' folder, then reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my Visual Studio, it got resolved.